# Auto-scrolling effect inside a table with elements

Tags: angular, html-table

Hopefully someone will be able give me at least some guidance on how to achieve this...
I am a newby in Angular and Web Development in general but I was kind of forced to create this application by using Angular :D

Essentially I have a component which only needs to display a table containing some info.
These info are automatically retrieved here from Firebase which are later poured inside an array:

```
ngOnInit{
this.dbService.getPlayers().then((players) => {
    this.players = players;
    });
}
```

This array will later be referenced to the HTML part where the table is declared and it looks like this:

```
<div class="content">
    <table class="table">
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let player of players" class="player">
        <td>{{ player.name }}</td>
        <td style="text-align: right">{{ player.points }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Everything fine with the first part but I have a particular requirement where the table once loaded with the data it should also automatically begin to scroll starting from the top going down to the bottom and then from the bottom going back to the top without the user performing any action and indefinitely more like a leaderboard basically.

I've tried numerous animations combinations but I still couldn't figure out how to make the animation continuous to go down the list and then go back up.
I've only managed to make the list scroll down by using this animations block inside the component:

```
animations: [
  trigger('scrollAnimation', [
    transition('* => *', [
      style({ transform: 'translateY(-100%)' }),
      animate('10s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateY(0)' }))
    ])
  ])
]
```

I don't think I'm very far from the desired result but I would appreciate if anyone could provide me any input.
I can share more code if needed from the component but it's pretty empty at the moment.